# ProgressDialog vs. AsyncTask - won't show

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I have an apparently clean code that just doesn't work, giving me no Exceptions or anything.

I have a trivial one-button Activity (`MainActivity`). The button in it calls an `AsyncTask` in order to send an email in the background. I tried to do what I guess it's a pretty common thing: show a `ProgressDialog` when the task starts and dismiss it when it ends. To do so I put the above-mentioned code into `AsyncTask.onPreExecute()` and `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`.
I thought the problem was in the `Context` provided to the dialog constructor, but I created a simple constructor for my `AsyncTask` to which I pass the application context. I added a simple `Toast` to debug, but it doesn't show up neither...

Here's the code for the button `onClick` method:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Sender(this).execute("args");
}
```

And here's the code for the task:

```
private class Sender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progDialog;
    private Context context;

    public Sender(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        protected void onPreExecute(Void... params) {
        Toast.makeText(this.context, "Sending...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.context, "Sending", "Picture is being sent...", true);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... mailSubj) {
        // some code that works
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void onPostExecute(Void... v) {
        progDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mail sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: did you try setting a breakpoint inside onPreExecute/onPostExecute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your progress dialog not show up because you don't override `onPreExecute()`. Add `@Override` annotation to your `onPreExecute()`, see what happens. `onPreExecute` takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake and the solution is straight forward: adding a `Void` list of arguments to `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` caused Java to not override the methods from `AsyncTask`. The first needs no arguments and the latter needs a single Result (in this case `Void`) argument.
This question can be closed.